# The views that render "general" templates where they should be (home.html, about.html, etc)? | Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I have templates for example like `home.html`, `about.html`, etc. Which are "general."

Where should the views that render these views be located?

I am not convinced to place these views in the applications of my project, since each one has a very specific purpose. It occurs to me to create an application specifically for these "general" views, but what should this application be called? Is it good practice to do it?

---

Another solution would be to put the views in the urlconf, as follows:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name = 'pages/home.html'), name = 'home'), # here
    ...
]
```

But is this alternative of good practice? 
Is there a much better alternative?

Comment: Put them in your base app since they might be used everywhere

Comment: What is the base application? I do not have that app.

Answer (score 0):

Just put them in your global app. Let's suppose my Django project name is `project_name` and I have an app called `tasks`. Here is what I would do:

```
~/projects/projects_name/

project_name/       # project dir (the one which django-admin.py creates)
    ...
  settings/         # settings for different environments, see below
    __init__.py
    ...
  views.py         # Put here global views (home, etc.)
  urls.py
  wsgi.py
  static/             # site-specific static files
  templates/          # site-specific templates
    project_name/
      home.html
      about.html
  tests/              # site-specific tests (mostly in-browser ones)
...


tasks/
    ...
    static/             # tasks app-specific static files
    templates/          # tasks app-specific templates
```

Comment: but is it good practice ?, I had not seen a views.py in the project_name ...

Comment: Yes it is. You can create it and create even a models.py.

Comment: Is there documentation about that? it looks very interesting..